# Why do I keep getting your connection to this site is not private

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a website that is working perfectly, it was developed using asp.net, however anytime I request a page that has crystal report I get a pop up message saying "your connection to this site is not private" and request for username and password.

What could be the problem

Comment: is the site using https?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: If the site is using HTTPS, does it have a valid Security Certificate?